# What status can a record of bolt cms have?

Tags: bolt-cms

When setting a record in the `bolt-cms`, there are multiple options for the status. What are they all, and what do they do? The documentation is not very clear what they are and what they are used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current status of this record can be either: published, depublished, held, draft or timed.

- **published**: a record has been published.
- **depublished**: this content should not be accessible, but still not deleted. Available since Bolt 4.
- **held**: this content should not be accessible, but still not deleted.
- **draft**: when a record is not ready to be published yet because it is unfinished. This is the default status for any contenttype that does not have a `default_status` setting.
- **timed**: used in combination with the `Publication date` field to publish a record in the future, or to have a record be published for a certain duration.

See also: https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/contenttypes/intro#the-structure-of-a-record and https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/howto/resource-contenttype#default-publishing-status